# MetaMask cannot add token

Tags: tokens, metamask

Ok, this has been asked before, but there was no solution. I am trying to add some token contracts to my MetaMask, but they simply do not show up. I am using the Chrome extension.

However, this issue happens only on my laptop. I also have a MetaMask wallet on my desktop PC for Firefox and it works just fine.

Is there something wrong with the laptop/Chrome extension? I had been able to add tokens just fine up until 1 month ago or so.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Same trouble with Chrome extension, found such related issues https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/2748 and https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/2675